# VB.NET or C#, silverlight datagrid binding

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I am looking for a way to execute sql on a connection, (any sql command that return data) and then bind the result to silverlight datagrid, is there anyway of doing this,

I don't want to use strongly typed objects!

Regards

Comment: Yes there is way of doing it. What have you tried? where do you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = new ItemsCollection();
```

where `ItemsSource` inherits `Collection<item>`

Check this out: [Different Ways to Bind Data Grid in Silverlight](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/433/posts/12021/different-ways-to-bind-data-grid-in-silverlight.aspx),